# Trying to wrap up a keras model in a flask REST app but getting a ValueError

Tags: python, flask, keras

I can create a simple keras model by running

```
python create-flask-model.py
```

**create-flask-model.py**

```
##points in square that are in or out of a quarter circle
import random
import math
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

training_size = 8000
testing_size = 2000
batch_size = 10
epoch_no = 30
modelStructureFileName = 'simple-flask.json'
modelWeightFileName = 'simple-flask.h5'

def get_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=2, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
    return model

def get_data_instances(size):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, size):
        number_1 = random.uniform(0,1)
        number_2 = random.uniform(0,1)
        squares = math.pow(number_1,2) + math.pow(number_2,2)
        target = 0
        if squares < 0.49:
            target = 1
        line = number_1,number_2,target
        result.append(line)
    return np.array(result)

##create data and split in to training and test, features and targets
data_instances = get_data_instances(training_size+testing_size)
train_x, train_y = data_instances[:training_size,0:2], data_instances[:training_size,-1]
test_x, test_y = data_instances[training_size:,0:2], data_instances[training_size:,-1]

##load model and train
model = get_model()
history = model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch_no, validation_data=(test_x, test_y))

##save the model
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(modelStructureFileName, 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights(modelWeightFileName)

##how to get prediction for an instance
#instance = np.array([0.3, 0.6])
#instance = instance.reshape(1,2)
#yhat = model.predict(instance)
#print(yhat)
```

I wish to load the resulting model in to a flask app and be able to pass instances as json objects and have predictions made and returned. Running

```
python flask-app.py
```

in the same directory as the model json and h5 files.

**flask-app.py**

```
import json
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask
from keras.models import model_from_yaml

app = Flask(__name__)
model = None
modelStructureFileName = 'simple-flask.json'
modelWeightFileName = 'simple-flask.h5'

def load_model():
    yaml_file = open(modelStructureFileName, 'r')
    loaded_model_yaml = yaml_file.read()
    yaml_file.close()
    global model
    model = model_from_yaml(loaded_model_yaml)
    model.load_weights(modelWeightFileName)

@app.route('/flask/<input>', methods=['GET'])
def predict(input):
    input_array = json.loads(input)
    instance = np.array(input_array)
    instance = instance.reshape(1,2)
    yhat = model.predict(instance)
    return str(yhat)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_model()
    app.run(port = 9000, debug = True)
```

If I navigate to *http://localhost:9000/flask/[0.3,0.6]* I get an error

```
builtins.ValueError
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_3/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I think it's something to do with the scope of the model in the app, but can't figure it out. If I load the model in the request method it works once, but then fails with another error. I only want to load the model once. How can I get the flask app to work as expected?

EDIT: I ended up using bottle instead of flask and it worked no problem.

**bottle-app.py**

```
from bottle import route, run
import json
import numpy as np
from keras.models import model_from_yaml

modelStructureFileName = 'simple-flask.json'
modelWeightFileName = 'simple-flask.h5'

yaml_file = open(modelStructureFileName, 'r')
loaded_model_yaml = yaml_file.read()
yaml_file.close()
model = model_from_yaml(loaded_model_yaml)
model.load_weights(modelWeightFileName)
print('model loaded')

@route('/bottle/<input>')
def predict(input):
    input_array = json.loads(input)
    instance = np.array(input_array)
    instance = instance.reshape(1,2)
    yhat = model.predict(instance)
    print(input_array, yhat)
    return str(yhat[0][0])

run(host='localhost', port=9000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because, you have multiple threads enabled in flask by default. Tensorflow models are not working well with multiple threads. You can read more about this in the below links

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5640
- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14356

The following workaround worked for me

```
global graph
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():
   model.compile()
   model.fit()

with graph.as_default():
   model.predict()
```

Comment: Many thanks for that information. I tried various combinations of the code you posted but couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: You should post your error, what you tried and what didn't work so that we can help

Comment: Hi, the error I get is posted above and have included scripts to reproduce it. An appropriate model can be obtained by running create-flask-model.py, it's a very basic model and should take less than a minute to produce. If flask-app.py is then run the error is produced.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with respect to flask API.

The problem is Flask API works only once and then after it gives errors. So, in that case, you should write `K.clear_session()` at the end of the API before the `return` statement.

And do not forget to write `from keras import backend as K` line at the top.